Backblaze-b2 cors issue nextjs
Hi all I'm trying to set up Backblaze for a nextjs app, but I'm getting cors error, in the first instance I thought that it was the bucket and I set the custom cors rules but it was not because I'm getting this error on b2.authorize().
I'm using it from localhost:3000

"corsRules": [
{
"allowedHeaders": [
"authorization",
"content-type",
"x-bz-content-sha1",
"x-bz-file-name"
],
"allowedOperations": [
"b2_upload_file"
],
"allowedOrigins": [
"http://localhost:3000"
],
"corsRuleName": "uploadFileFromLocalHostAndWebSite",
"exposeHeaders": [
"x-bz-content-sha1"
],
"maxAgeSeconds": 3600
}
],

Has anyone experienced this issue? Do I have to use the master key?


async function uploadToB2(file: Blob) {
  const b2 = new B2({
    applicationKeyId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPLICATION_KEY_ID as string,
    applicationKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPLICATION_KEY as string,
  });
  const auth = await b2.authorize();

  console.log(auth);
}






I have the exact same problem, did you solve it?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/78429497/7123519

yes, in my case using the, i moved all the logic to a backend endpoint and started working fine. seems it fails from the client side if the bucket is private.

I just recently figured out how to make it work on the frontend with a private bucket: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78432306/7123519

The fix to this is to set a cors rule using the cli:
b2 update-bucket --cors-rules '[
    {
        "corsRuleName": "downloadFromAnyOriginWithUpload", 
        "allowedOrigins": [
           "*"                    
        ],
        "allowedHeaders": [
            "authorization",
            "content-type",
            "x-bz-file-name",
            "x-bz-content-sha1"
        ],
        "allowedOperations": [
            "b2_download_file_by_id",
            "b2_download_file_by_name",
            "b2_upload_file",
            "b2_upload_part"
        ],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]' (your bucket name)

you need to authorise in the cli before you can run this command

I tried that but it didn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78429497/7123519

Hi - glad you figured out the problem! Could you mark this answer as 'accepted' so that it's clear that it was answered correctly?
